# IMG won't show on remote site

Tags: html, css, image

I have a webpage where the images are not being found (running chrome). I synced the remote directory with my local one, so all files should be identical, however I can see the images locally but not on the remote site. Can anyone explain why?

I have the following directory where my index.html is:

icons/circle/*.png, where * is some generic social media i.e. (facebook, twitter, etc.)

using this code to show it on html

```
<img class="social-media" src="icons/circle/facebook.png">
```

But it only shows when I view my webpage locally, not when everything is uploaded to the server.

See webpage footer at dmacmill.com

Full directory listing:

[image]

## Temp solution

I decided to just create another folder to hold all my icons, now they work for some reason. Still never found out the underlying cause of this.

Comment: What happens when you type the URL directly into the browser? http://yoursite.com/icons/circle/facebook.png ? If it shows then your document base url is not where you think it is, if it does not show then it could be a setting on your webserver.

Comment: It says access restricted

Comment: can you show us where you put /icons/circle/ , because links are corrects ,but files are not located in this path

Comment: Access restricted I would check the permission settings for the images. Try setting them to 644

Comment: if .htaccess exists , delete it in circle and icons,else create .htaccess file with allow from all as content and put it in 2 folders

Comment: I tried taking away the .htaccess file, then visiting the link to the icon and it said 404 not found.

Comment: see the full directory listing here:
http://i.imgur.com/fcsyIje.png

Comment: Permissions are 755 for the icons folder and subfolders

Comment: I can see those icons right now on your website. Server cache maybe? Or did you change something?

Comment: Sorry guys, I edited my original question a while ago with my workaround solution. I cannot post an answer to my own question due to lack of reputation sadly.